# Chart.js cartesian axes - Modifying tool-tip based on which y-axis the data corresponds to

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a chart which has 2 Cartesian axes on the y-axis. I want to modify the tool-tip when hovering over a data point based on which y-axis the datasets corresponds with. One y-axis represents dollar amounts, while the other is percentages.

I currently have a working example, where it formats properly when hovering over the data but it is ugly and based on specific numbers. Where if the value is less -33 or greater than 101, it considers it a dollar amount.

```js
const yLabel = (-33 >= t.yLabel) || (t.yLabel >= 101) ? t.yLabel.toLocaleString("en-US", {
          style: "currency",
          currency: "USD"
      }) : t.yLabel + '%';
```

**Is there any real way to modify the tool-tip to correspond with the y-axis it uses?**

```js
const chart1 = new Chart(document.getElementById("chart").getContext('2d'), {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ["Customer 1", "Customer 2", "Customer 3", "Customer 4"],
    datasets: [{
        label: "Customer Check",
        data: [20000, 50000, 30000, 15000],
        fill: false,
        backgroundColor: "#d2d2d2",
        yAxisID: 'first-y-axis'
      },
      {
        label: 'Carrier Rate',
        data: [10000, 30000, 25000, 22000],
        fill: false,
        backgroundColor: "#adadad",
        yAxisID: 'first-y-axis'
      },
      {
        label: 'Margin',
        data: [10000, 20000, 5000, -7000],
        backgroundColor: "#4080ff",
        barPercentage: 0.6,
        yAxisID: 'first-y-axis'
      },
      {
        label: 'Profit Margin',
        data: [50, 40, 16.6, -46.6],
        type: 'line',
        yAxisID: 'second-y-axis',
        fill: false
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    tooltips: {
      callbacks: {
        label: function(t, d) {
          const xLabel = d.datasets[t.datasetIndex].label;
          const yLabel = (-33 >= t.yLabel) || (t.yLabel >= 101) ? t.yLabel.toLocaleString("en-US", {
            style: "currency",
            currency: "USD"
          }) : t.yLabel + '%';
          return xLabel + ': ' + yLabel;
        }
      }
    },
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
          id: 'first-y-axis',
          type: 'linear',
          position: 'left',
          ticks: {
            callback: function(value, index, values) {
              return value.toLocaleString("en-US", {
                style: "currency",
                currency: "USD"
              });
            }
          }
        },
        {
          id: 'second-y-axis',
          type: 'linear',
          position: 'right',
          ticks: {
            callback: function(value, index, values) {
              return value + "%";
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.chartjs.org/dist/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id='chart'></canvas>
```

In the example, you can see customer 4 had a **-46.6%** margin which in this case breaks my tool-tip callback because on hover displays **-$46.60**. If you `console.log(t)` and `console.log(d)`, there is no real useful information for which y-axis it is using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further inspection into variable `d` (data), it actually returns the `yAxisID` attribute. Which is exactly what is needed for matching the data points to their corresponding y-axes. `yAxisID` is defined in `y-axes`, so you can test against the names you have provided.

```js
const axisId = d.datasets[t.datasetIndex].yAxisID; // returns axisID
```

See [here](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html) for tooltip documentation.

The following code now works, test axis id for the defined axis and adjust `t.yLabel` based on it:

```js
tooltips: {
    callbacks: {
      label: function(t, d) {
        const xLabel = d.datasets[t.datasetIndex].label;
        const axisId = d.datasets[t.datasetIndex].yAxisID; // returns axisID, defined below
        if (axisId === "first-y-axis")
          return xLabel + ": " + t.yLabel.toLocaleString("en-US", {
            style: "currency",
            currency: "USD"
          });
        return xLabel + ': ' + t.yLabel + "%"; // if axis ID does not match first, then %
      }
    }
}
```